# Переопределение чисто виртуального деструктора

Tags: c++

Рассмотрим следующий абстрактный класс:

```
class Abstract
{
    // ...
    public:
    virtual ~Abstract() = 0;
}

Abstract::~Abstract()
{
}
```

Очевидно, что создать экземпляр такого класса нельзя, потому что деструктор класса `Abstract` помечен, как чисто виртуальный. Но... Для этого чисто виртуального деструктора существует реализация.

Таким образом, мы можем отнаследоваться от класса `Abstract`, и при компиляции не возникнет ошибки, связанной с тем, что наследник не может вызвать чисто виртуальный деструктор.

Как это работает? Это какое-то особое правило?

Я столкнулся с этой особенностью в следующей ситуации:

У меня есть базовый класс, который нужно было сделать абстрактным. Так как все виртуальные методы моего класса имели определение и не являлись чисто виртуальными, я решил сделать виртуальным именно деструктор. Я принял такое решение, потому что не видел смысла добавлять *костыльную* чисто виртуальную функцию, единственное назначение которой - запретить создание экземпляров базового класса.

В общем, затем я сделал примерно так:

```
class Concrete1 : public Abstract;
class Concrete2 : public Abstract;
```

И был удивлен тем, что переопределять чисто виртуальный деструктор предка нужно только в одном из наследников. При попытке сделать так:

```
Concrete1::Abstract::~Abstract(){}
Concrete2::Abstract::~Abstract(){}
```

Я получаю от компилятора сообщение о том, что происходит переопределение `~Abstract()`.

Хочу разобраться в следующем:

- Что происходит, если деструктор объявлен, как чисто виртуальный, но при этом такой деструктор имеет реализацию?
- Почему я не могу переопределить чисто виртуальный деструктор в независимых наследниках?

Comment: Допустим - все работает так, как вы хотели. Адрес *какого именно* деструктора следует поместить в таблицу виртуальных функций базового класса?

Comment: @Harry, то есть, можно просто объявлять деструктор предка как чисто виртуальный, а затем сразу же предоставлять этому деструктору реализацию прямо через `Abstract::~Abstract(){}`? Просто я думал, что каждому наследнику можно задать персональный деструктор базового класса.

Comment: Вообще-то я не вижу другого варианта. Если не дать реализации деструктора - то такой объект нельзя будет уничтожить. Пусть гуру стандарта скажут, соответствует ли возможность дать реализацию чисто виртуальной функции стандарту, но, насколько я знаю - да, соответствует.

Comment: @Harry, [_A pure virtual function need be defined only if called with, or as if with (class.dtor), the qualified-id syntax (expr.prim.id.qual)_](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.abstract#2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вызов деструктора базового класса из деструктора класса-наследника всегда является *прямым* вызовом, а не виртуальным вызовом. На такой вызов никак не влияет тот факт, что вызываемый деструктор является pure. Ситуация совершенно аналогична любому другому pure методу с явно определенным телом: вызвать его через виртуальный механизм нельзя, а через прямой (т.е. с использованием *квалифицированного имени* метода) - можно.

```
struct A
{
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

void A::foo() {}

struct B : A
{
  virtual void foo() 
  {
    A::foo(); // <-- вызываем A::foo
  }
};

int main()
{
  B b;
  b.A::foo(); // <-- вызываем A::foo
}
```

Стандарт языка специально [говорит](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#9), что при вызове базовых деструкторов из деструктора наследника

> ... All destructors are called as if they were referenced with a **qualified name**, ...

т.е. вызов делается с подавлением виртуального механизма (и, соответственно, pure таким вызовам никак не мешает).

---

Возможность определения

```
Concrete1::Abstract::~Abstract(){}
```

для меня навскидку явилась сюрпризом, но по здравом размышлении я вижу, что ничего удивительного в этом нет. В данном случае `Concrete1::Abstract` - это [*инжектированное*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name) в класс `Abstract` его собственное имя, затем унаследованное в класс-наследник `Concrete1`. То есть `Concrete1::Abstract` является синонимом `Abstract`. И ваши определениея

```
Concrete1::Abstract::~Abstract(){}
Concrete2::Abstract::~Abstract(){}
```

являются стопроцентным эквивалентом просто

```
Abstract::~Abstract(){}
Abstract::~Abstract(){}
```

А это множественное определение одного и того же деструктора.

Зачем вы именно так вычурно их написали - не ясно. С таким же успехом можно было написать

```
Concrete1::Concrete1::Abstract::Abstract::Abstract::Abstract::~Abstract(){}
Concrete2::Concrete2::Concrete2::Abstract::Abstract::Abstract::~Abstract(){}
```

Но ясно, что если вы один и тот же метод определите несколько раз, то получите ошибку множественного определения. Что вы и наблюдаете.

Comment: `Concrete1::Abstract::~Abstract(){}` переопределяет виртуальный деструктор базового класса, и это переопределение видят все, кто наследуется от базового класса? Поэтому, переопределение должно быть одно? Вот этот момент я не совсем понял.

Comment: @MGNeo: `Concrete1::Abstract::~Abstract(){}` эквивалентно просто `Abstract::~Abstract(){}`. Зачем вы использовали такой вычурный синтакисис? Но в любом случае множественные определения `Abstract::~Abstract(){}` приведут к ошибке.

Comment: большое спасибо за вашу помощь.